# How to execute a command when computer are no longer in "idle" state? (win10-11)

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I find very useful to change "balanced" powermode to "power save" (and some other settings) when dont using my nettop (like 97% of time). On idle condition in task scheduler are works okay, but how to do the opposite - execute another task when its not in idle anymore? Tryints "on log in" or "on unlock" or "on connection to user session" - not working (but i'm not using the passwords and lockscreen not shows...)